# How to convert list elements to string using Python?

Tags: python, type-conversion

How should I convert list elements to string using Python?

For example I have a list that looks like this:

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And I want it to look like this:

```py
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Comment: `lst=list(map(str, lst))` where `lst` is your input list

Comment: Please add a sample input and expected output. This question is very vague. Take a look at writing [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Use a one-liner to iterate over all elements it an `Iterable` and use `str(element)` to cast the element as a string

```py
new_list = [str(i) for i in old_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def listToString(a):  
    li = []
    for i in a:
         li.append(str(i))
    return li
```

We can input the list in the function.